# Loading a scene in Unity twice causes some game objects to lose some components

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

When I hit play the game scene behaves as normal, **even if I come from a different scene**.

But when I am on the game scene and go to other scene and back again to the game scene some components from some game objects.

I am using `SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName");` to move around scenes, and **every component was added in the editor and saved in the scene**.

And as an example here is the *Game Manager* inspector at first load of game scene:

[image: first load]

And second load of game scene:

[image: second load]

*Windows Controls* is a script much like the others missing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, I was short-sighted, I used a singleton pattern to access the managers and the way I did, at least, doesn't work in this context.

Any manager that I needed access I created a static instance, but since I checked for its existence elsewhere, the second time the component was destroyed.

```cs
public GameManager Instance {get; private set;}

void Awake()
{
  if(Instance is not Null && Instance != this)
  {
    Destroy(Instance);
    return;
  }
  Instance = this;
}
```

I realize that every time the scene loads the components are new objects, but I am still to understand why there is still copies of the old components.

I fixed it by using the `[SerializeField]` on any manager reference that I could and and manually adding them on the inspector, for some game objects that were instantiated at run time I pass the manager in a method.

```cs
GameManager gameManager;
public void Manager(GameManager _gameManager)
{
  gameManager = _gameMananger;
}
```

```cs
GameObject gameObject = Instantiate(prefab);
gameObject.GetComponent<Script>().Manager(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what's going on inside the GameManager and the FoodManager scripts, I think you use the [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) similar what is showed on the bottom of the page, and your code destroys the scripts.

Comment: thanks, when I read better my code with fresh eyes I understood what was happening, it was indeed my code that was deleting the components.